# How Read File Path From a .dat file then open the program When Pressing The Launch Button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a problem Where I cant make my program automatically read the given file path inside the .dat and be ready to launch the program when pressing launch file without opening openFileDialog and choosing the program every time.

the code im using here is for the user to enter the file path for the first time then create a file path .dat file and it works with now issues.

```
using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string path = Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat");
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = filePath;
                openFileDialog.Filter = " PlayGTAV (*.exe)|PlayGTAV.exe";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                         fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    }

                    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(filePath);

                    }
```

After that that i have a start button for it

```
private void panel21_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start(filePath);
        }
```

This works well when the user does it for the first time but now I want it to read that .dat file path automatically without having to ask the user for the file path every single time which I don't know how to do and need help with please.

I was thinking to do it like that: When Pressing the Launch button (After the first time) The Program Checks if the Fail-SafePath.dat Exists if Yes it reads the lines from it and starts the program from the given path without opening OpenFileDialog.

I'm Using Visual Studio, Windows Form.

Comment: Even reading the title tells me that this is not an appropriate question. Reading a file path from a file and executing a file are two separate, unrelated operations. One of those is irrelevant to this question. If you're having trouble with both then you should be asking two separate questions. If you're only having trouble with one, why is the other in the title, which should be a summary of the issue? Having read the question, it appears that the title doesn't even address the actual issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a file that the application will always need, then something like you mentioned:

> I was thinking to do it like that: When Pressing the Launch button (After the first time) The Program Checks if the Fail-SafePath.dat Exists if Yes it reads the lines from it and starts the program from the given path without opening OpenFileDialog.

Could work easily enough. You could have your application look for it in the default location, and if not there, have your user select it.

Another solution could be using something like [**Application Settings** or **User Settings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), which are values persisted between executions of .NET projects.

Depending on your full application design, you could also have the file path and other settings stored in some database or other data storage. There are a lot of ways to accomplish this.

**EDIT:** To elaborate further on the Application Settings

The application settings are very easy to [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) and [write](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to.

You just need to create the ones you want, before trying to use them.

They can be [created by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-new-setting-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

> 1. Open Visual Studio.
> 2. In Solution Explorer, expand the Properties node of your project.
> 3. Double-click the .settings file in which you want to add a new setting. The default name for this file is Settings.settings.
> 4. In the Settings designer, set the Name, Value, Type, and Scope for your setting. Each row represents a single setting.

To read from your settings:

```cs
this.FilePath= Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath;
```

To write to and save the setting:

```cs
Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath= Path.GetFullPath("importantFilePath");  

Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: Thank You This Worked Perfectly. This Is what i used.

`string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
string path = Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat");
string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat"));

VL.Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath = Path.GetFullPath(text);
 VL.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

 filePath = VL.Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath;

Process.Start(filePath);`

Comment: With that code you are performing multiple actions that have similar goals. You may want to check the FilePath property first, and if it is null or missing, then you can have your code that prompts the user to select a file and load it from the desktop, that way you don't have to load the failsafe file each time.

Comment: Ibrennan20 I have already done that there is a separate Button To start from the default install directory if its not found it will ask the user to locate the custom install directory using this code then saving it and remembering the custom directory on their next start which I tested and it seems to work without any issues so I guess its fine.

Comment: The code you show in your comment will try to read a file on your desktop every time you run it, and then it tries to set the Application Setting, and then read that same setting, which is unnecessary based on the use case you are describing. If you wanted to share more of your code I can point out what may need some adjustment, but just as a starting point I would suggest actually using the `path` variable you create like so 

```c#
string path = Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat"); 
string text = File.ReadAllText(path); 
```

Comment: I see I think I understand now so what I'm doing wrong is making the program save the file path every time the user starts it. so what I did is moved the saving part to the custom Dir button so when the user wants to locate the file it will also saves that path. So now the Start custom DIR button looks like that.

`string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                string path = Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat");

                filePath = VL.Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath;

                Process.Start(filePath);`

Comment: I also Removed This Part
`string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);                 string path = Path.Combine(desktop, "LS\\Fail-SafePath.dat");`

So now its just this code:

`filePath = VL.Properties.Settings.Default.FilePath;
Process.Start(filePath);`.

Comment: It seems like you are on the right track. If it is still giving you issues or you have other questions I would be happy to join a chat room and go over the code for you at some point.